# How to find Oracle APEX Interactive report template

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex, interactive

I need to make style changes to Oracle apex IR (apex version 4.2). For that purpose where can i find the template of it. ? is it saved inside table or procedure ?

Answer (score 2):

Interactive reports are held in a region and the region can have a template, but has no effect on its content, such as an IR.
**While you can define report templates for classic reports, this is not possible for interactive reports**.

**You cannot** control the structure (html) it puts out.
**You can** however change the style of it by applying CSS to the appropriate elements. You don't have need to alter the source it puts out. Defining selectors and using your browser tools to inspect everything you can definitely influence the look and feel.

Word of warning though: heavily applying CSS will bring some trouble when upgrading to apex 5, as IRs have been changed a lot. This means you'll have to change selectors quite a bit while also doing more setup on the IR.

If you'd supply more info on the kind of change you'd want to make to the IR, answers could be more specific and concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Read these article for customizing report template

http://www.apexninjas.com/blog/2011/03/customizing-report-templates/

http://rimblas.com/blog/2014/05/using-conditions-with-column-templates/

http://www.eberapp.com/pls/apex/f?p=BLOG:READ:0::::ARTICLE:5976400346831048

http://apex.shak.us/post/1145946801/fully-control-your-interactive-reports-toolbar

You can create new template under apex:
Application Builder/Application #/Shared Components/Templates

Comment: let me be more specific, i need to change the look and feel of the IR control section .. not the data display.

Comment: Please provide detail of requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can find Oracle Interactive reports template from

- > **PAGE RENDERING SECTION**
- > Right Click your **INTERACTIVE REPORT**
- > Click **Edit Report Attributes**
- > Then template is under Layout and Pagination Section

But i doubt you can edit the template in there.
If you are looking for adding a template to be used in your report then follow these steps

- > Go to the **Main Page** of your application
- > Then go to **Shared Components**
- > Then Search for **User Interface** Section
- > Under this section, Click **Templates**, this is where you can add template for any type of item(report, region, page, etc..)